# Bounty not showing on featured questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured

It doesn't show the bounty amount anymore (I swear it used to)... why should I of made my question +250 when I could just make it +50 and it gets the same standing as all the other questions in there?  The whole point of giving a bigger bounty is to attract more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed - thanks for the report.  I would like to blame caching, but not this time :)